# How to pull names for a .txt file into your python code

Tags: python

I have a .txt file name TXBabynames, and I need to see what name is the most popular for males and for females. There is about over 1000 entries in this document. I am not sure how to go about getting this data into my python code.

```
Babies = open ("c:\TestData\TXBabyNames.txt")`

FemaleCount = 0 
MaleCount = 0
femaleyear1910 = 0
maleyear1910 = 0
femaleyear2012 = 0
maleyear2012 = 0
totalbabies = 0
myname1910 = 0
myname1910to1960 = 0
name = []

Babies.readline()

for line in Babies:
    element = line.strip().split(",") 
    state ,sex ,year ,name, Freq = element
    if sex == "F":
        FemaleCount = FemaleCount + 1
    if sex == "M":
        MaleCount = MaleCount + 1
    if sex == "F" and year == "1910":
        femaleyear1910 = femaleyear1910 + 1
    if sex == "M" and year == "1910":
        maleyear1910 = maleyear1910 + 1
    if sex == "F" and year == "2012":
        femaleyear2012 = femaleyear2012 + 1
    if sex == "M" and year == "2012":
        maleyear2012 = maleyear2012 + 1
    if year == "2012":
        totalbabies = totalbabies + 1
    if name == "John" and year >= "1910":
        myname1910 = myname1910 + 1
    if name == "John" and year >= "1910" and year <= "1960":
        myname1910to1960 = myname1910to1960 + 1

print('The total number of females are :' +str (FemaleCount))

print('The total number of males are :' +str (MaleCount))

print('The total number of females born in 1910 is:' +str(femaleyear1910))

print('The total number of males born in 1910 is:' +str(maleyear1910))

print('The total number of females born in 2012 are:' +str(femaleyear2012))

print('The total number of males born in 2012 are:' +str(maleyear2012))

print('The total number of babies born in 2012 are:' +str(totalbabies))

print('The total number of babies with my name since 1910 are:' +str(myname1910))

print('The total number of babies with my name in between the years 1910 and 1960 are:' +str(myname1910to1960))
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for here? How to read the file contents from your code?

Comment: that depends a lot on: how the data is formatted, how the file is encoded, what you want to do with it etc... Can you give some details and post your code as of now?

Comment: You will need to open, read the file, and store the information in instance of one of Python's container classes, like dictionaries and list.

Comment: So this is part of an assignment. I have answered all other questions, the last one is to find out the most popular name for females and males, and I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from collections import Counter

males, females, johns = Counter(), Counter(), Counter()
with open("c:\TestData\TXBabyNames.txt") as baby_file:
    for line in baby_file:
        element = line.strip().split(",") 
        state, sex, year, name, freq = element
        if sex == "M":
            males[year] += int(freq)
        elif sex == "F":
            females[year] += int(freq)
        if name == "John":
            johns[year] += int(freq)

print('The total number of females are: ', sum(females.values()))
print('The total number of males are: ', sum(males.values()))

print('The total number of females born in 1910 is:', females['1910'])
print('The total number of males born in 1910 is:', males['1910'])

print('The total number of females born in 2012 is:', females['2012'])
print('The total number of males born in 2012 is:', males['2012'])
print('The total number of babies born in 2012 are:', females['2012'] + males['2012'])

print('The total number of babies with my name since 1910 are:', sum(johns[year] for year in johns if int(year) >= 1910))

print('The total number of babies with my name in between the years 1910 and 1960 are:', sum(johns[year] for year in johns if 1960 >= int(year) >= 1910))
```

If you want more detailed analyses based on names (not just John), you can make the Counter nested (a `defaultdict` of Counters), but the generator comprehensions get a bit longer, then.

---

I just saw your comment about wanting to find the most common male and female names: In that case, I'd ignore the years (assuming they don't matter) and just make it two `Counter`s with names as keys.

Comment: I tried running the code above and get ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: How many female records are there? How many male records are there? How many female records are there in 1910? How many male records are there in 1910? How many female records are there in 2012? How many male records are there in 2012? What are the total number of babies born in Texas in 2012? What are the total number of babies born in Texas with your name since 1910? What are the total number of babies born in Texas with your name between 1910 and 1960? If you have a very uncommon name, feel free to pick any name that you might be curious about.

Comment: What name was the most popular (had the highest count in one year): * For males * For females

What name was that? * For males * For females

What year was that? * For males * For females
In what year was your name the most popular (had the highest count)?

Comment: These are the things I have to get using the code

Comment: @JLuna I don't have your baby file, so it's really hard to test.

Comment: I understand. Is there was a way I could send it to you?

Comment: You can put the first few lines (assuming they contain all relevant cases) in your question. But I won't just solve your homework.